# std::shared_ptr operator= changes the object, not the pointer value?

Tags: c++

In the little program below, I wanted to be able to change the value inside `M m` by changing the value of `s`. But apparently I cannot do it. One way that would work would be to change the raw pointer but this is not safe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class M{
  public:
  std::shared_ptr<int> t;
};
std::shared_ptr<int> s;
int main() {
  M m;
  m.t = s;
  s = std::make_shared<int>(5);
  std::cout << m.t << std::endl; //prints 0
}
```

On this little program, I thought that by doing `s = std::make_shared<int>(5)`, `s`'s internal pointer would point to `5`. However, what it does instead is substitute the value of `s` by another value, so `m.t` is not pointing to the new `s`.

Isn't it possible to do what I want?

Comment: The entire function of a shared pointer is to safely pass around a pointer, as if it were just a raw pointer.  That means `m.t = s` simply copies the pointer that `s` is currently managing, and stores it in `t`.  Then it updates its internal reference count so that if one of `s` or `t` go out of scope, the pointer will not be deleted.  If you then change what `s` points at, it should _not_ change `t`, because `t` does not know about `s`.

Comment: If you want that changing of contents of `s` effects `m.t` as well then you have to change the _contents_ of `s`. Try `*s = 5; std::cout << *m.t << std::endl;`. Regarding this, smart pointers resemble exactly how raw pointers would work in this case. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60b98be835bb2098)

Comment: You have the order swapped around.  Do the `s = std::make_shared<int>(5);` first, then do the `m.t = s;`.  After that you can `*s = 6;` or `*m.t = 7;`, either of which will affect the other shared smart pointer.